# Read in files from list of lists

Tags: r, data.table

I have a bunch of files for which I created lists for such as below:

```
a_files <- list.files(path="./Afiles/", full.names = T)
b_files <- list.files(path="./Bfiles/", full.names = T)
c_files <- list.files(path="./Cfiles/", full.names = T)
d_files <- list.files(path="./Dfiles/", full.names = T)
e_files <- list.files(path="./Efiles/", full.names = T)
```

And a list of the following lists:

```
list_of_lists <- list(a_files, b_files, c_files, d_files, e_files)
```

I'm trying to now read in each of those lists to their own respective dataframes as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_of_lists)){
 temp <- fread(list_of_lists[i], stringsAsFactors = F) 
 i <- rbindlist(list(i, temp_data), use.names = T)
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in fread(file_list[i], stringsAsFactors = F) : 
  input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r
>
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong, and how to properly get this done?

In the end the I want dataframes (a_files, b_files, c_files) containing the contents of each folder. The files in each folder are of identical column width (all A files have the same 10 columns, with varying number of rows, all B files have the same 40 columns with varying number of rows, etc.)

Comment: `a_files` have multiple filenames in it, right?

Comment: Your are trying to read each of those vectors of file names as a list.

Comment: Hi Ronak, Yes a_files, etc all have multiple filenames/paths in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread` (or any other way to read data) reads only one file at a time. You can try.

```
library(data.table)
group_lists <- lapply(list_of_lists, function(x) rbindlist(lapply(x, fread)))
```

You can use this list for further manipulation or if you want them as separate dataframe, you can assign names to them and then use `list2env`

```
names(group_lists) <- paste0(letters[1:5], '_files')
list2env(group_lists, .GlobalEnv)
```